# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'split'. How I can fix it?

Tags: python

How i can fix it? What I can to do with this error?

https://github.com/dandayo/formyhoneygirl/blob/main/main.py

```
def link():
    with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

    with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as s:
        image_url = json.load(s)
        print(image_url["url"])


filelName = link.split("/")[-1]+".jpg"

answer = requests.get(link, stream=True)
```

Comment: Post the full stack traceback (error message) into the question. It'll tell exactly which lines are causing the error.

Comment: please add more details.  The problem I can see is you are using split method on a function. It only operates on a string.`filelName = link.split("/")[-1]+".jpg"` is the line causing problems

Comment: https://github.com/dandayo/formyhoneygirl/blob/main/main.py
 here is all the code

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please let us know where the error occurs next time, it will make it easier to answer your question.

The issue seems to be with the fact that you are... well.. Indeed calling the function itself and trying to split it, which understandably throws the error. There are 2 things that are wrong with your code:

1. You're not returning anything from the function. Use `return image_url['url']` instead of print. Right now all you're doing is simply printing the value to the console and that's it. Your function returns `None`.
2. You're using `link.split()`, when you should be calling the function by using `link().split()`.

Comment: https://github.com/dandayo/formyhoneygirl/blob/main/main.py
here is all the code ...

Answer (score 1):

`link` is a function, which incidentally returns nothing.

`split` splits nstrings.

`link.split("/")` tries to split the function.

Hence, the error.